# How can I add two cases for same column in vb.net to manipulate data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, case

I once had a doubt to entering data. This code was given by Joen in here and this work 100%. Now I need to upgrade it to write two cases in one. I need to add another CASE like this:- **Count2 = CASE WHEN Today_Date <> current_date THEN Count2 = 0 How to put this code?**

```
UPDATE attendance.dateverification 
SET Count1 = CASE WHEN Today_Date <> current_date 
                  Then Count1 +1 
                  ELSE Count1 END, 
    Count2 = CASE WHEN Today_Date = current_date 
                  THEN Count2 + 1 
                  ELSE Count2 END, 
    Today_Date = current_date, 
    Subject_selected = @subject 
WHERE Subject_Name = @subject; 

SELECT Subject_Name, Today_Date, Count1, Count2 
FROM attendance.dateverification
```

Comment: You have a whole database dedicated to attendance?

Comment: `Count2 = CASE WHEN Today_Date != current_date THEN 0 ELSE ??? END`. If you'll skip ELSE section then NULL will be assigned which condition is FALSE. But this will contradict with existing expression which assigns `Count2` value...

Comment: What has this question got to do with VB.NET? SQL is SQL. The SQL code doesn't change based on the language used to write the application that executes it. Don't spam tags.

Comment: Strawberry. I have a table only for this code segment.

Comment: Akina. So what can I do? Is it okay if I skip it?